# Amazon Wowza Users Handling

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, server, rtmp, wowza

I'm working on RTMP live streaming protocol. However, I'm going to setup Amazon pre-configured Wowza Engine in EC2. I'm doing some researches, find out the I/O performances for instances actually like bandwidth for instances.

According to this [post](http://www.powpark.com/blog/streaming/2013/05/09/setting-up-wowza-media-server-for-live-video-streaming),

```
High: Theoretical: 1Gbps = 125MB/s; Realistic (source): 750Mbps = 95MB/s
Moderate: Theoretical: 250Mbps; Realistic (source, p57): 80Mbps = 10MB/s
Low: Theoretical: 100Mbps; Realistic (from my own tests): 10-15Mbps = 1-2MB/s
```

I'm taking Twitch.tv recommendation broadcasting setting example [here](http://help.twitch.tv/customer/portal/articles/1262922-open-broadcaster-software). I'm streaming 240p with 500kbitrate to my rtmp server.

My instance has low I/O performance which only can serve up to 1-2MB/s. So if let say has 100 users simultaneously view my video stream, 500kbitrate = 62.5kb/s x 100 = 6.25MB/s, izit the minimum bandwidth I need to handle 100 simultaneously. So moderate I/O performance will be minimum requirement for this because it handles up to 10MB/s.

I just want to know how much instances I need to handle 10,000 viewers on my website that full of live streaming platform. If my users getting lots, my broadcasters getting a lots, so I need to create more instances to standby ? Is Amazon CloudFormation can help me reduce this ?